# What is the 'cacert.pem' and for what to use that?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, domain, ssl-certificate, localhost

I am developing a web application on *localhost* with domains and sub-domains and I would like to use a *HTTPS* connection. On my Mac OS, in order to enable SSL, I need to set Apache correctly, so I followed some guide to accomplish part of that.

Now it is time to choose a certificate in order to test HTTPS requests. I seen the **[cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)**, but I don't know how to use that and for what it is used (*can you explain to me some about its usage?*)...

So, **is it possible to use the `cacert.pem`** ([see the link](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)) **for *all* my domains and subdomains (maybe, as a *wildcard certificate*) on localhost?**

- **If so, how to do that? What certificate I have to take and use?**
- **If no, what I need to do in order to use a *wildcard certificate* for *all* my domains and subdomains on localhost?**

Of course those certificates must be accepted by browsers and working for HTTPS connection between my domains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cacert.pem` is a collection of trusted root certification authorities. You can't use these to secure your own site. There are a number of reasons, but mainly: you don't have the matching private key.

You site certificate contains a public key that is used by the client to encrypt messages to your server that can only be decrypted by the matching private key.

Your question suggests a lack of understanding of public key cyptography. Granted, you can get a lot done without it, but it helps to read up on the basics:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure
- And from there, some great finger-puppet guides: http://www.carillon.ca/tutorials.php

To correctly generate the keys and certificates you need, this guide is useful, and specific to Apple/Apache/mod_ssl: http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html

Comment: Both links of carillon.ca and apple.com are broken.  I have edited your answer to reflect the new information as current, if you dont mind.

Comment: Link to the apple website is broken. It redirects to the Safari browser home page.